# Copying Table Range and Pasting as Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that updates an inventory sheet from another downloaded report by dropping formulas into some table cells, but I need to change them to just values instead of the formulas after updating.

I just need to copy the full column (which needs to be a variable amount of cells) and then paste it right back into the same spot, but as values. (Similar to manually copying, pasting, and then doing ctrl+v again to paste as values)

I'm open to any solutions as long as the cells become values.

I've tried standard ListObjects Range Copy code with PasteSpecial, but I get an error 438, "Object doesn't support this property or method" when it gets to the pasting line. I can't figure out what other options I have based on research I've done.

```
 '''This is the formula going into the cells

 ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", '[8-14-19 AM INVENTORY.xls]Sheet2'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """)),0,GETPIVOTDATA(""Sec QTY Sum"", '[8-14-19 AM INVENTORY.xls]Sheet2'!$A$4,""Alias"",""" & y & """))"

 '''The second line of this code is where it messes up with the error 438

 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table62").ListColumns(5).Range.Copy

 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table62").ListColumns(5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Trying to get values so that the spreadsheet isn't dependent on another spreadsheet being open/unchanged. Getting error message 438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a late-bound member call, so *IntelliSense* can't help you. Error 438 happens when you code blindfolded against `Object` or `Variant`, and try to guess what members exist on the runtime interface of the object you're working with... and the member happens to not exist.

`ActiveSheet` is an `Object`. Make it a `Worksheet`.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet 'cast to Worksheet, don't work with Object.
```

Copying and pasting are `Range` operations, so work with the `Range` property:

```
With sh.ListObjects("Table62").ListColumns(5).Range
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

None of the involved properties/objects here are `Object`, so everything is early-bound and you get autocompletion/intellisense every step of the way. Making sure your code is always early-bound is the single best way to avoid error 438.

That said, working with `ActiveSheet` is a trap here: if the active sheet doesn't have a table named `Table62`, expect run-time error 9 "subscript out of range". If you mean to be working with a specific worksheet, *work with a specific sheet*, not just whatever sheet happens to be active.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly. I even had that worksheet defined as a variable already, but wasn't using it for this specific line of code when I should have. I was working around the specific sheet problem by activating the sheet I was working with before doing any "ActiveSheet" functions.